Windows EventLog parsing
I am parsing event log records to detect various power states. One state in particular gives me a problem - unexpected power loss (id 6008).
The event has 2 properties inside - DATE and TIME stored as strings. The issue is that these datetimes are stored in such format, that does not match any of the datetime formats on user machine.
For example:
Event stores - Time: 5:31:04 pm, Date: 27/02/2024
PC detected patterns - Time: h:mm tt, Date: M/d/yyyy
In the example you can see, that day and month location does not match, time is in long format, while date is in short.
Is there any way to parse datetime from string, when format pattern not necessarily matches the computer's locale settings.
Edit:
Referring to the comment - crash event creation time stamp does not necessarily matches the event timestamp. It seems that event record is getting created, on next computer boot which might happen way way later.
For example, the actual event happened at 6:06:42, yet computer got booted after half an hour and event creation date is 6:32:21


The eventlogentry has TimeGenerated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlogentry.timegenerated?view=netframework-4.8  why do you need to parse a string?

Sounds like i lead, need to check it. Thank you
